# R: Transposing from long to wide and aggregating rows with matching ID

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation, transpose, reshape2

This is something I've been working around for a while just making separate data frames and doing full_join but I think there's an easier way.

Overall, I'm wanting to calculate the differences between an individual ID's value from time 1 to time 2 by type from a long form data frame.  This is one of the ways I think I could do it but if other people have other techniques or ideas I'd like to hear them too.

However, I'd also like to know how to address this transposing issue anyway because I'm curious.

Here's my issue.

I have a data frame in long form with 5 different measures for two different time periods.  I want to convert this data frame from long form into a wide form so that instead of having a DF look like this (note, not all types are included -- just did 2 for sake of length):

(example df1)

```
ID   Time  Value  Type
1     1      7     Type1
1     2      8     Type1
2     1      9     Type1
2     2      10    Type1
1     1      13    Type2
1     2      15    Type2
2     1      17    Type2
2     2      19    Type2
```

I want it to look more like this:

(example df 2)

```
ID   Type1.1   Type1.2    Type2.1  Type2.2
1      7          8          13      15
2      9          10         17      19
```

I use:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df.new <- df %>%
spread(Type, Measurement.Value)
```

and get this from example df 1 which is on the right track:

(example df 3)

```
ID    Time    Type1    Type2
1       1       7        13
1       2       8        15
2       1       9        17
2       2       10       19
```

But now I want to spread the time for each type.  When I do something like this on example df3:

```
newer.df <- df.new %>%
spread(Time, Type1)
```

to make this:

```
ID   Type1.1   Type1.2
1      7          NA 
1      NA         8 
2      9          NA
2      NA         10
```

So, it's producing an NA for each row -- is there a way I can collapse rows on to each other by ID?  I think I'm missing something.

Remember, in my example code I'm only using 2 types but in reality I have 5 types -- just wanted to give simplified code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dcast()` from `reshape2` package.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, ID ~ Type + Time, value.var = "Value")
#  ID Type1_1 Type1_2 Type2_1 Type2_2
#1  1       7       8      13      15
#2  2       9      10      17      19
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much. I did try using the `reshape` package using `cast()` but was getting the same issue.  I'm glad to see that `reshape2` had my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Or using the original `tidyr` package, we could do this:

```
library(tidyr)
df$Type <- paste(df$Type, df$Time, sep="_")
df$Time <- NULL
spread(df, key=Type, value=Value)
 ID Type1_1 Type1_2 Type2_1 Type2_2
  1       7       8      13      15
  2       9      10      17      19
```

Nulling the time column did the trick for me. It seems that `spread` considers all columns not used otherwise as what `dcast` would call `id.vars`. There might be a more elegant solution using `tidyr`, though.

Comment: This solution also worked.  Thank you!  Yeah I suspect there's something more elegant than having to transform the variables like that. Either way, it worked so thank you.